# Get text between start pattern and end pattern based on pattern between start and end pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to get everything between `startStr` and `endStr` for case `bbb`. I understand how I can get all occurrences between `startStr` and `endStr` using `sed`. I do not see how I would constraint it just to the one instance where `bbb` occurs.

Sample input:

```
fff
startStr
aaa
bbb
ccc
endStr
xxx
yyy
startStr
ddd
endStr
ddd
bbb
```

Required output:

```
startStr
aaa
bbb
ccc
endStr
```

This is what I have:

```
$ sed -n -e '/startStr/,/endStr/ p' sample.txt
startStr
aaa
bbb
ccc
endStr
startStr
ddd
endStr
```

Comment: Has to be `sed`?

Comment: No, anything similar would work as well - awk, grep, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For first `startStr`…`endStr`, contains `/bbb/` occurrence:

```
 sed -n '/startStr/ {:n; N; /endStr/ {/\n[^\n]*bbb[^\n]*\n/ {p; q}; b}; bn}'
```

or

```
sed -n '/startStr/ {:n; N; /endStr/ {/\nbbb\n/ {p; q}; b}; bn}'
```

if `bbb` is not regular expression and it is exactly string you need (from begin to `\n`).

#### Explanation

For address `/startStr/` we:

- set label `:n`;
- read next line with `N`;
- check that it matches `/endStr/`;

  - if it's true, check `/\nbbb\n/` occurrence in this block we read;

    - if it is present, do `{p; q}` for «print and quit»,
    - otherwise, do `b` for «throw this block and start to search next»;
- if it isn't end of block, we jump to `:n`, i.e., continue reading.

Comment: Did you notice that the question mentions `bbb`?

Comment: I looked at "Required output" section.

Comment: For this "Required output" it's ok, but if OP has different file, it might not work as they want.

Comment: I've understood you, you're right. So, i've fixed script, thanks.

Comment: Much better.  See [this answer](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/228699/80216#228703 "sed - Print lines matched by a pattern range if any one line matches a condition") for a slightly streamlined version.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend `pcregrep` for this job:

```
pcregrep -M 'startStr(.|\n)*?bbb(.|\n)*?endStr' sample.txt
```

Option `-M` allows to match multiline patters, and the `*?` in no greedy operator. The rest should be obvious.

Comment: I don't have pcregrep, but I tried the possible equivalent `grep -ozP '(?s)startStr(.|\n)*?bbb(.|\n)*?endStr\n'` ... the problem is if there is a block of `startStr...endStr` without `bbb` before the block containing `bbb`, all lines from the first `startStr` to second `endStr` get filtered... just interchange order of the two blocks in OP's input to check it...

Answer (score 2):

Modified input sample to include block of `startStr...endStr` without `bbb` before matching block

```
$ cat ip.txt 
startStr
foo
bar
endStr
fff
baz
startStr
aaa
bbb
ccc
endStr
xxx
yyy
startStr
ddd
endStr
ddd
bbb
```

`awk` solution

```
awk '/startStr/{f=1; m=0; buf = $0; next}
     /bbb/ && f{m=1}
     f{buf = buf ORS $0}
     /endStr/ && f{f=0; if(m==1)print buf}
    ' ip.txt
```

- `/startStr/{f=1; m=0; buf = $0; next}` set flag to indicate start of block, clear match, initialize buffer and move on to next line
- `/bbb/ && f{m=1}` if line contains `bbb`, set match. `f` is used to avoid matching `bbb` outside of `startStr...endStr`
- `f{buf = buf ORS $0}` as long as flag is set, accumulate input lines
- `/endStr/ && f{f=0; if(m==1)print buf}` at end of block, print buffer if match was found

as one-liner:

```
$ awk '/startStr/{f=1; m=0; buf = $0; next} /bbb/ && f{m=1} f{buf = buf ORS $0} /endStr/ && f{f=0; if(m==1)print buf}' ip.txt 
startStr
aaa
bbb
ccc
endStr
```

A simpler `perl` solution by slurping entire input file - assumes that there are no blocks like `startStr...startStr...endStr` (i.e no endStr for the first startStr)

```
$ perl -0777 -ne '(@m) = /startStr.*?endStr\n/gs; print grep { /bbb/ } @m' ip.txt 
startStr
aaa
bbb
ccc
endStr
```

Comment: +1  for identifying `startStr...startStr...endStr` as (another) ambiguity in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Python solution:

```
$ ./find_bound_pattern.py < input.txt                                                                                    
startStr
aaa
bbb
ccc
endStr
```

Script itself:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

flag = None
group = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    if 'startStr' == line.strip():
        flag = True # mark beginning of the block
        group.append(line.strip())
        continue
    if flag: # we are in a block, so record lines
        group.append(line.strip())
    if  'endStr' == line.strip():
        flag = False # reached end of block, time to check
        if 'bbb' in group:
            print('\n'.join(group))
        group = [] # clear list after each block end
```

The way this works is quite simple: we mark the beginning of the block with `flag` variable, and unset it once we reach end of block. Once we reach end of block - we check what we recorded for presence of `bbb`, and print out all the strings. The recorded list is cleared at the end of each block and process repeats again, so this is suitable for matching multiple blocks which may contain `bbb`.

The logic in this approach is simple, can be implemented with other languages such as C, Java, or Ruby - whichever your heart desires. Note that in this case, this is more of a line-matching problem, but if there is a need for more advanced pattern matching, it can be implemented as well via `re` module.

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -n -e '/startStr/,/bbb/p;/bbb/,/endStr/p' /path/to/input
```

Comment: To me this returns 11 rows. Looks like union of rows 2-4 and 4-13?